Mapped value determined by custom field not saved
I have created a custom field that has a pick list of 5 possible options. I have then added 5 different custom rules that set the value of the Size field based on the option selected for the custom field. I'm finding that Work Items that already had a value in the Size field prior to me creating the custom rules show with the correct value when I view the Work Item (so that's good). However, when running a query, it will still show the original value the Size field had prior to the rules being added in the query results. When I then click on the Work Item in the list of query results it will update the value shown for the Size field to the value I have defined in the custom rules. So although the correct value is displayed when opening a Work Item, that value is not actually saved on the Work Item.
The value set by the custom rules only seems to get saved on the Work Item if the user updates another field on the Work Item and then saves. What I expected was that the custom rules would set the value of the Size field regardless of that field already having a value prior to configuring the custom rules.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Work Item Rule to set the Size field value.
When I use the Work Item Rules to set the Size field value based on custom field, it will show manually input value in Query(if we input the value before rule execute) instead of the work item rule input value.
For example:
Rule:

Query Result:

Work item Detail Page:

As you said, we need to modify other fields and save the work item. Then the correct value will show in the query.
The issue is from the Azure DevOps Boards feature itself. I suggest that you can report the issue to Developer Community. Azure DevOps Developers will investigate this Product issue further.

Thanks for confirming it is an actual problem - so I take it there is no workaround solution other then the users having to open, edit & save the work item? I wonder if the rule that first clears a field value might be used somehow?

@Serow11 Based on my test, edit other fields and save work item is the only workaround for the time being. I am afraid that rule will not first clear the field value and apply the correct value. But you can create a feedback ticket on Developer Community. I think the product team will solve this issue from product level.

@Serow11 If you have posted the ticket to Developer Community, you can share the link here. And I will help you monitor the update.
